# Retraction and fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

If we know $\pi_1(X),\pi_1(Y)$, what we can say about existence of retraction $X$ onto $Y$ and vice versa.
I think if $\pi_1(X)$ is 'smaller' than $\pi_1(Y)$ there is no retraction $X$ onto $Y$.

For example if $X = S^1\times D^2$ and $Y = S^1 \times S^1$ there is no retraction $X $ onto $Y$ because $\pi_1(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $\pi_1(Y) = \mathbb{Z^2}$

Are there some results about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X\rightarrow Y$ is a retraction, then the inclusion $Y\rightarrow X$ induces a morphism $\pi_1(Y)\rightarrow\pi_1(X)$, which is an injection by functoriality, hence $\pi_1(Y)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$. This gives an obstruction, e.g. if $\pi_1(X)$ is trivial and $\pi_1(Y)$ is not then we cannot have a retraction $X\rightarrow Y$.
This addresses your very nice example, since $\mathbf{Z}^2$ certainly cannot be isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: What we can say about existence of retraction if $\pi_1(Y)$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of $\pi_1(X)$?

Comment: @user2715119 are you looking for existence results alone or also for nonexistence results? (the way I read your question you are looking for both) You cannot really show existence using the fundamental groups alone; they can be used to give obstructions (necessary conditions for existence).

Comment: But maybe with some another conditions we can show existence using fundamental groups?

Comment: @user2715119 perhaps, but I doubt that algebraic conditions (e.g. on fundamental groups) alone suffice.